# Powershell Runspace Iteration

Tags: powershell

I've written a script that quantizes images and copies everything to different folders and scales them to fit specific devices. It now works within a runspace and is much quicker, however no matter how deep I dig into the powershell instance I can't iterate based on the number of times the script is run in one of the threads.

```
$MaxThreads = 4

#Create Run Spaces
$RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,$MaxThreads)
$RunspacePool.Open()

$ScriptBlock = {
    Param (
        [array]$files
    )

    #copy files
    #quantize images

}

$RunningJobs = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
1..$MaxThreads | ForEach-Object {

    $src          =   $gfxfolder

    $Job = [powershell]::Create()
    $Job.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool

    [void]$Job.AddScript($ScriptBlock)
    [void]$Job.AddArgument($files)

    [void]$RunningJobs.Add((
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Files = $files
            PowerShell = $Job
            Handle = $Job.BeginInvoke()
        }
    ))
}

While ($RunningJobs.handle[0].IsCompleted -eq $false) {
    #do stuff whilst it's running, handle[0] always finishes last and is a good approximation of the progress
}

$return = $RunningJobs | ForEach-Object {
    $_.powershell.EndInvoke($_.handle)
    $_.PowerShell.Dispose()
}

$RunningJobs.clear()
$RunspacePool.Close()
```

In this case I wish to count up each time $ScriptBlock has been run so I can pass the details to a progress bar.

If this is not possible or there's an easier way to do this I'd appreciate knowing how. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Count the output?  Here's foreach-object -parallel in powershell 7.  Hmm, write-progress doesn't update quite right.

```
1..20 | foreach -parallel { sleep 5; "$_ done" } | 
  foreach { $i = 1 } { 
  $_
  write-progress progress ($i/20*100) -percent ($i++/20*100) }
```